# importing NumPy in Parallel Python

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

everyone,I am new to PP but got stuck in a problem when importing NumPy with PP.

Basically what I tried to do was submitting a function to the ppserver which depends on NumPy. I have imported it at the very beginning of the code using (import NumPy as nu) but when I ran the code, it gave me the error that cannot find the shared object multiarray.so.

The situation is exactly the same here: [parallel python forum](http://www.parallelpython.com/component/option,com_smf/Itemid,1/topic,655.msg1785#msg1785)

the code is attached as below: (I am running on python 2.7.2 + pp 1.6.0 + numpy 1.5.1)

```
import numpy as nu
import pylab as pl
import pp
job_server = pp.Server(secret="123456")
print "Starting pp with", job_server.get_ncpus(), "workers"

aa = GrRib()
job = job_server.submit(aa.plotwavefunc, (band,k),(nu,pl,signal))
result = job()
```

the error looks like :

```
An error has occured during the function import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/ppworker.py", line 86, in run
    exec __fobj
  File "<string>", line 127, in <module>
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
      its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
      your python intepreter from there.
An error has occured during the function import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/ppworker.py", line 86, in run
    exec __fobj
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/matplotlib/colors.py", line 52, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/numpy/__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: No module named multiarray
```

Can anyone help me out? I understand it as I will have to change the directory PP is looking for pyshared objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I believe the way you submit the job is wrong. As seen on the documentation (http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/15/30/#QUICKSMP), the third argument (not including "self") are dependent functions. Also, the modules have to be strings. I'm assuming the "band" and "k" are dependent functions since I do not see their declarations:

```
job = job_server.submit(aa.plotwavefunc, depfuncs = (band,k), modules = ("numpy","pylab","signal"))
```